# Play Framework RSS module

Tags: playframework, rss, playframework-2.0

I am looking at building an RSS feed into an Play Application.  Is there a module I can use to do this simply?  I found the cnm module but I'm trying to go further than annotating the method to only accept application/rss+xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this for a [demo app](https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/tree/play2_java) a while ago.  Here is [the relevant commit](https://github.com/jamesward/happytrails/commit/b111c01d5a3f739b3f6a0839ca5828d5bd00e8b4#diff-93c1ebbcb555c5f7d8ee08519974efa6)  that uses the `rome` library and adds a controller that assembles and returns RSS.

Comment: Hey James, looks like Rome is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks for the sample code too, it'll definitely help me get off to a good start.